# Using Keycloak for login with gitlab account in an app

Tags: java, spring-boot, gitlab, keycloak

I'm building a Java SpringBoot app and I tought of using Keycloak to permit users to login with their GitLab account.

How can I do that? Is there any article or tutorial about this process?

Comment: I'm not sure why keycloak would be necessary here at all. You can use GitLab directly as an identity provider. Maybe it would help if you provide more details about your use case. Do you only need user identities? Do you need to interact with GitLab on a user's behalf?

Comment: I tought of using Keycloak because I need to integrate WSO2 in this app and manage roles of users.